# Changing the default output file handler in Matlab

Tags: matlab, stdout, printf

I think it would be useful, at least I find so, and I searched for but did not find anythign appropriate.

Supposing you have a set of lines that use stdout, or these lines are included in a function. Then I need to change the output stream to a file. But not with diary() and such.

Example:

```
ShowResults(...)   % this is a function containing a lot of fprintf('asdasdasd', ...)
                   % which by default shows messages on monitor
```

then I need something like:

```
ShowResults(...)   % this will now output to monitor
setOutputHandler(my_file_pointer); % setup redirection
ShowResults(...)   % this will now output to the file
setOutputHandler(stdout);
```

or even better something like:

```
setOutputHandler(stdout, my_file_pointer);
ShowResults(...)   % this will now output to the file and monitor at the same time
setOutputHandler(stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Especially if you use `fprintf` in your function, the easiest would be to define an additional input that you'd use as first argument in each call to `fprintf`

By default, that additional input would be set to 0, which means `fprintf` prints to screen. Alternatively, you can pass a file identifier created by `fopen` to `showResults`, so that `fprintf` would write to file.

If that is infeasible, you can always use `capturedOutput = evalc('showResults(...)')`, which will capture all the outputs in an array, from which you'd write to file.

Comment: Ok, nice answer. But it is not transparent. I mean look at my ideal example code... Is there anything that does not affect your main code, but just changes the stdout with another handler?

Comment: @argyris: as far as I know, evalc is the only way to redirect output, but it will redirect it into an array.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately `evalc` seems to be the only way to redirect output :(